# PHPDoc / PhpStorm protected members in autocomplete list

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

Is it possible to display protected members in autocomplete list?
For example:

```
class Foo
{
    protected $bar;
    public function __get($name) { return $this->$name; }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo-> // display autocomplete list with bar
```

I use PhpStorm 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@property` in class-level PHPDoc comment.

https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#714-property

```
/**
 * @property ProperTypeHere $bar [Optional description]
 */
class Foo
{
    protected $bar;
    public function __get($name) { return $this->$name; }
}
```